# Перевести формулу в Delphi

Tags: delphi, математика

Как мне следует написать правую часть равенства

[image]

при заданном вещественном x и натуральном n. В правой части должно быть n слагаемых. Я планировал использовать цикл у условный оператор, но в этом случае ответы получаются абсолютно левыми.

```
program formula;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;
var
  i,n:integer;
  s,a,x:real;

begin
  readln(x,n);
  s:=1-1/2*x;
  a:=1/2*x;
  for i:=2 to n do
  begin
    a:=-a*(2*i-1)/(2*i);
    s:=s+a;
  end;
  write('s=',sqrt(1-x):8:4, ' s=',s:8:4);
  readln
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Odd Функция](http://delphibasics.ru/Odd.php) проверяет четное число или нет

Заводите 2 переменные в одной считаете верхнюю часть, в другой нижнюю часть.
Дальше простая математика.
Дальше циклом, писать полностью код влом, выложите свой подскажу в чем ошибка.

Comment: program formula;

    {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

    uses
    SysUtils;

    var
     i,n:integer;
     s,a,x:real;
    begin
    readln(x,n);
    s:=1-1/2*x;
    a:=1/2*x;
    for i:=2 to n do
    begin
    a:=-a*(2*i-1)/(2*i);
    s:=s+a;
    end;
    write('s=',sqrt(1-x):8:4, '    s=',s:8:4);
    readln
    end.

Comment: конечно полный бред и будет.
Возведения в степень вообще нет,в общем рсписуйте в строчку полностью пример и пытайтесь нписать.

Comment: @savro: возведение в степень и не нужно, в `a` вычисляется текущее слагаемое на основе предыдущего

Answer (score 3):

В строке `a:=1/2*x;` добавьте минус в правой части.

В строке `a:=-a*(2*i-1)/(2*i);` домножьте правую часть на `х`.

В выражении `sqrt(1-x):8:4` вы забыли про степень `-1` и зачем-то вычили x, когда надо прибавлять.

[Работающий пример](http://ideone.com/6LOBTr).

Comment: У меня равны. `s=  0.9535    s=  0.9535`

Comment: Имейте в виду, что данный ряд сходится, при `|x|<1`.

Для медитации http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Bx%29